# react-native-custom-tabs Cannot read property 'openURL' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using react-native-custom-tabs package but it doesn't work.

I tried on RN and snack.expo.io but there is no difference.

```
import { CustomTabs } from 'react-native-custom-tabs';
```

I imported package like that.

```
componentDidMount(){
    CustomTabs.openURL('https://www.google.com').then((launched: boolean) => {
   console.log(`Launched custom tabs: ${launched}`);
 }).catch(err => {
   console.error(err)
 }); 
}
```

I used the openURL method like that. But I got this error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'openURL' of undefined

Function.openURL -> CustomTabsAndroid.js:26:29

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you link the project using `rnpm link`

Comment: I linked already, thanks for your comment. Everytime I build it crashes. I did everything to build.

Comment: What is your setup and what guide did you follow, just so I can follow your steps.

Comment: I use create-react-native-app for expo. So in my app directory I installed ("npm install -S react-native-custom-tabs") and I linked ("rnpm link").
Every package runs after these. I imported and it doesn't work. Just it.